# The name for predicting future rolls of dice based on the past

Tags: probability, terminology, dice

My friends and I were playing a game where you roll dice and you bet money on what picture it's going to land on and I began reasoning with myself that if I tallied up what pictures the dice landed on that the ones it has not landed on were more likely to come up in the next roll of the dice.

So I began a process of observing two rounds and tallying up the results and then on the third round betting on the pictures that have not come up yet hoping that they would make their appearance on the next roll.

Although I do not have any mathematical proof to verify this. Does anyone know what this phenomenon is called if it is even possible or if it is possible?

Edit: I figured it out its called "Gambler's fallacy"

Comment: You need to be clear that rolls of the die are independent. So you would focus on how many additional spaces  you would move on the 2nd roll beyond your position reached on the first.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after a little Bit of google searching its called Gambler's fallacy